# Возможна ли переадресация с домена на домен через файл HOSTS?

Tags: iis

Есть ссылка, адрес которой ведёт на отключённый сайт. Имеется адрес, подменяющий этот сайт. Сайты организованы на IIS. Возможно ли организовать переадресацию по доменным именам в файле **HOSTS**?

Comment: нет. hosts отвечает только за преобразование доменного имени в ip-адрес

Comment: Причём локально - т.е. HOSTS на сервере в принципе не способен изменить что-то на клиенте.